# How to define function using open()

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python, trying to create simple code that pulls a txt file, and returns the first word from it. I'm getting a NameError, telling me that "name 'folder' is not defined".
code and folder > txtdocument are in same directory.

```
def first_word(file):

    text = open(file).read().strip().split()

    return print(text[0])


first_word(folder/txtdocument.txt)
```

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: You are missing quotes on `folder/txtdocument.txt` and you don´t need to call `print()` in the return statement.

Comment: When posting, include the full traceback message which will show us the full error text, the failing line, and a list of functions called.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has few errors in it. I have debugged them. The Path of the txt file must be string but yo haven't kept quotations for txt file path. we don't need to return the print statement we can simply print it.

```
def first_word(file): 
    text = open(file).read().strip().split()
    print(text[0])

first_word("folder/txtdocument.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

The path needs to passed as a string; Also you would be returning a call of the print method instead of the actual value.

```
def first_word(file):
    text = open(file).read().strip().split()
    return text[0]


print first_word("folder/txtdocument.txt")
```

should be what you are looking for.

Comment: @quejordy Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean. You can define the string separately, but then you would not add the quotation marks like you did, so it would just be:


file = "folder/txtdocument.txt"

Comment: Probably worth throwing some parentheses around that `print` call. If the OP's class is still using Python 2, it's a lost cause anyway, so we should probably teach 3.x patterns nowadays